# Select Only Characters after First Character in String

Tags: sql, sql-server, string

Sample results before string manipulation:

```
COLUMN1   |   
-----------
A343jsk    |
------------
Jsdefss    |
------------
Vdkekd     |
------------
Nod        |
------------
An         |
------------
```

How do I achieve:

```
343jsk    |
------------
sdefss    |
-----------
dkekd     |
-----------
od        |
-----------
n         |
-----------
```

I tried this:

```
SELECT 
    COLUMN1 - LEFT(COLUMN1,1) 
FROM 
    Table
```

however this does not work.  Obviously I can't use `RIGHT` because result strings are not all the same length.

Comment: Couldn't you use `RIGHT(column1, LEN(column1) - 1)`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [SUBSTRING()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187748.aspx):

```
SELECT 
    SUBSTRING(COLUMN1, 2, LEN(COLUMN1) - 1) 
FROM 
    Table
```

Alternatively, (as @David Faber pointed out) you could use:

```
SELECT 
    RIGHT(column1, LEN(column1) - 1) 
FROM 
    Table
```

[I personally prefer the first form]

Comment: Thanks.  I will accept as answer when the allowed time to accept has elapsed

Comment: Dollars to doughnuts the execution plan would be exactly the same.